# Include an external css file in vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack

I generated a hello-world project with @vue/cli and now I would want to include an external .css file in my App.vue

Then I tried this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
@import url("../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("../assets/css/panel-rescue.css");
@import url("../assets/css/animate.css");
</style>
```

But when I run `npm run serve` this is showing up:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                            2:06:05 PM
These dependencies were not found:

* -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!../assets/css/animate.css in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
* -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
* -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!../assets/css/panel-rescue.css in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&

To install them, you can run: npm install --save -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!../assets/css/animate.css -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!../assets/css/panel-rescue.css
```

Then I installed css-loader `npm install -D css-loader` and I tried a lot of way to setup it in the app with `webpack.config.js` and `vue.config.js`, but anyway that I tried fail.

I took a look to the documentation of vuejs and css-loader I'm lost.

**Edit** solved: 
`@import url("../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");`
by
`@import url("./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it:
Changed

```js
@import url("../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

to

```js
@import url("./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

The double `.` led me to one folder above.

Comment: Same issue here. The path was invalid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use :

```
<style lang="sass">
  @import "@/path/file.css";
</style>
```

`@` is an alias to `/src`

Comment: Strange. I use it daily. But since you solved your problem this is not a big deal. :)

Comment: I just got it works by using it this way: 
`<style lang="scss" src="@/assets/css/vue-multiselect.scss"></style> `

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method. https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/604#issuecomment-287620657. If its not work

```
<script>
import '../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'

export default {
}
</script>
```

try this.